# Postgres Interval Returns Decimal Numbers

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, intervals

I'm trying to calculate interval between 2 timestamp fields and to get the result with numeric numbers instead decimal.

I already had this issue on 'seconds' field and I resolved it with 'date_trunc', but now I have it again on 'hour' field.

ex: `date_trunc('seconds', (time1 - time2)) = 3.20:54:32`

Comment: I don't understand the question `numeric` and `decimal` are the same thing in Postgres. And `interval` is a completely different data type. What exactly is the result you expect?

Comment: 3.20:54:32  => what does it mean '3.20'? I guess 3 days and 20 hours, but I want it to be only in hours like - '92:54:32' or '3 days 20:54:32'

Comment: If you calculate interval between 2 timestamps, you get an interval like this `select '20220315 15:25:31'::timestamp - '20220312 08:59:02'::timestamp` = `3 days 06:26:29` [Result here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=ef2c14dab5f1f93e474f42b5cf306ef9)

Comment: It would help to include the values for `time1` and `time2` and the output from `show intervalstyle;` in `psql`.

Answer (score 1):

The subtraction of 2 timestamps produces an interval (as you have already seen). Then you can extract the individual components from the resulting interval and apply the necessary multiplication to convert to the desired period: So:

```
with times (t2, t1 ) as 
     (values ('20220315 23:53:34'::timestamp, '20220312 02:59:02'::timestamp)  )
     
select elapsed
     , round( ( extract('days'   from elapsed) * 24  
              + extract('hour'   from elapsed)  
              + extract('minute' from elapsed) / 60.0 
              + extract('second' from elapsed) / 3600.0 
              ) 
           , 2) total_hours
  from ( select t2 - t1  elapsed from times) duration;
```

Result:

```
+-----------------+-------------+
|     elapsed     | total_hours |
+-----------------+-------------+
| 3 days 20:54:32 | 92.91       |
+-----------------+-------------+
```